# How to upload files to shared folder in google drive as shared folder owner's quota?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have to move a set of backup files of a web application day by day to google drive.  For this my friend created a folder in the google drive and shared with me with edit permission so he can also the see the backup files.

So I created a application(with python) using the google drive api and started to upload files to google drive. After some 7+ uploads(7*2gb size for  each file =14gb) the api started to raise an error shown below

**An error occured: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&alt=json returned "The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota">**

Then I checked my storage and it shows "14gb used out 15gb".

Why this is happening? Actually I uploaded the files to the shared folder created by my friend and now it shows those are uploaded in my quota. Also tried with the drag and drop option, but it is also uploaded in my quota

I have the following questions

1) How can I upload the files to the shared folder in my friend's quota?
   2) Is it possible to upload only 15gb data through my account? or How can I increase my quota?

Comment: Guessing here: change the owner permission of the file to him not you.  If you own the file even if its on his drive its probably under your quota.

Comment: Thanks Dalm you are almost right, 

but how can I change the file's ownership? I can see the ownership change setting for the shared folder from the **share->advanced** options.  Is there any option to change the ownership of a single file?